# How to give xml start tag with attributes in xmlinputformat hadoop

Tags: xml, hadoop

I want to parse xml file in `hadoop`. It contains a tag like

```
<article name="..." year="...." />
```

If I give `article` as my start tag in `xmlinputformat start_tag_key` it doesn't recognize the article tag since my file contains article tag with attributes.

How can I specify `start_tag_key` in `xmlinputformat` for the above mentioned article tag.

Comment: Is this issue resolved?

Answer (score 2):

If your XML start tag is containing attributes like

```
<article name="..." year="...." />
```

Then you should use your start tag and end tag as:

```
configuration.set("xmlinput.start", "<article");
configuration.set("xmlinput.end", "</article>");
```

Do not close your first article tag,so that it will take that tag as a tag with other attributes. You don't need to specify the attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify it like this -

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("xmlinput.start", "<article>");
```